# C# - Unsure how to fix errors related to custom classes/types copied from someone else's code

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to fetch the list of dynamic distribution groups from an Active Directory, and someone pointed me to a [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431322/looking-for-help-accessing-dynamic-distribution-lists-using-c-sharp-and-adws) with code that supposedly works, but I am not 100% sure how to make all the parts of this code work, as the link only contains a portion of their code. I added a couple of using statements and a couple of structs and the DistributionList class at the bottom, but I am unsure of how to get rid of the error that the Settings.ImpersonatedUserDomain line throws because it says that 'ImpersonatedUserDomain' is not defined in 'Settings'. I also am having trouble with the line

> dl.DType = new DLT.DDL.set();

because it says that the type name 'DDL' does not exist in the type 'Class2.DLT', even though I have already defined it in the struct below. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. I would comment on the Stack Overflow question, but I don't have enough reputation. Can anyone help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Configuration;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Security;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; 
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using NuGet.Configuration;

/* This code may only be usable over a VPN*/
/* Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431322/looking-for-help-accessing-dynamic-distribution-lists-using-c-sharp-and-adws*/


public class Class2
{
    //public object Settings { get; private set; }

    public List<DistributionList> GetDynamicDistributionLists(string strEmailAddress)
    {
        List<DistributionList> distributionLists = new List<DistributionList>();
        String DomName = "dc=" + Settings.ImpersonatedUserDomain.Replace(".", ",dc="); 

        using (var group = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + DomName))
        {

            using (var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + DomName))
            using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot, "(&(ObjectClass=msExchDynamicDistributionList)(proxyAddresses=smtp:" + strEmailAddress.Trim() + "))"))
            using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (SearchResult result in results)
                {
                    if (result.Properties.Contains("cn") && result.Properties.Contains("msExchDynamicDLFilter"))
                    {
                        DistributionList dl = new DistributionList();


                        dl.DType = new DLT.DDL.set(); 
                        dl.CN = result.Properties["cn"][0].ToString(); // 
                        dl.FILORDN = result.Properties["msExchDynamicDLFilter"][0].ToString(); 
                        distributionLists.Add(dl);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return distributionLists;
    }

    public struct DLT
    {
        public List<String> DDL { get; set; }

    }

}

public class DistributionList   
{
    public struct DLT
    {
        public String DDL;
    }

    public DLT DType { get; set; }
    public string CN { get; set; }
    public string FILORDN { get; set; }
    public List<string> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I led you down this path, so I should probably help you.

That code has some things specific to their implementation that you don't need. `Settings.ImpersonatedUserDomain` seems to be a setting they created that gets pulled from somewhere else. But it's just the name of the domain. I have no idea what `DLT.DDL.set()` does, but you probably don't need it.

You should also be looking at the `msExchDynamicDLBaseDN` attribute too. It may turn out to be the same on every DL, but just in case...

That code also takes the email address of one dynamic DL and gets the details of just that one, where, if I remember correctly, you want to get all of the dynamic DLs on your domain. If I'm correct in that, this is how I would do it:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

public class Class2
{
    public static List<DistributionList> GetDynamicDistributionLists()
    {
        var distributionLists = new List<DistributionList>();
        var domain = "example.com";
        
        // Find all dynamic DLs
        using (var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{domain}"))
        using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot, "(objectClass=msExchDynamicDistributionList)",
            new [] {"cn", "msExchDynamicDLFilter", "msExchDynamicDLBaseDN"}
        ))
        using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                if (result.Properties.Contains("cn") && result.Properties.Contains("msExchDynamicDLFilter"))
                {
                    var dl = new DistributionList {
                        Name = (string) result.Properties["cn"][0], 
                        Filter = (string) result.Properties["msExchDynamicDLFilter"][0],
                        SearchRoot = (string) result.Properties["msExchDynamicDLBaseDN"][0]
                    };
                    distributionLists.Add(dl);
                }
            }
        }
        
        //Get membership of each DL
        foreach (var dl in distributionLists) {
            using (var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{dl.SearchRoot}"))
            using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot, dl.Filter, new [] {"distinguishedName"}))
            using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (SearchResult result in results)
                {
                    dl.Members.Add((string) result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]);
                }
            }
        }

        return distributionLists;
    }
}

public class DistributionList   
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public string SearchRoot { get; set; }
    public List<string> Members { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Set `domain` to the name of your domain. This will populate the `Members` collection with the `distinguishedName` of each member. You can change that if you'd rather have the email (use the `mail` attribute), or anything else.

Comment: Thanks so much! Why don't you need to log into the server?

Comment: What do you mean by "log into the server"?

Comment: When I made a program that performed a similar function in PowerShell, I had a line that contained the username/password of an admin of the user domain. Do I not need a similar line for this C# program?

Comment: By default, it uses the credentials of the user that is running the program. You can add credentials to the code if you need to run it as a different user, or you can just use the "Run as" feature in Windows.

Comment: I keep getting an exception at the line ```using (var results = searcher.FindAll())``` and the exception is "System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: 'The user name or password is incorrect.'" I've tried handling it with a try catch statement, but the same error just reappears in the next section that is like that. I tried adding a statement that took in the username/password of the admin, but it didn't help.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you running the program under credentials that work on the domain you are accessing? If not, then you will have to provide credentials when you create `searchRoot` (in both places), like this: `searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{domain}", "username", "password")`